# Keras model gives: loss: 0.00, val_loss: 0.00 while training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I have been working on an NLP project for sentiment analysis. I have a movie review dataset. I was able to preprocess, vectorized, and pad the data successfully but when I train my model with the dataset my loss and validation loss stays 0.
I am sure that I did something wrong so here are some parts of the code:

```
VOCAB_SIZE = 20000
EMBEDDING_DIM = 16
MAXLEN = 250
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Embedding(VOCAB_SIZE, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=MAXLEN),
tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')])
###
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
         optimizer='adam',
         metrics=['accuracy'])
###
deneme12 = model.fit(train_PAD, train_LABEL, epochs=10,
                validation_data=(test_PAD, test_LABEL), verbose=2)
```

Here is the result of the training process:

```
Epoch 1/10 1291/1291 - 10s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/10 1291/1291 - 10s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00
```

Comment: Try using the `keras` library itself instead of `tf.keras`. The one inside tensorflow seems to have trouble with this, though it isn't supposed to be a problem here because you are passing validation data as a tuple. See if that gives you better results.

Comment: will try, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are doing a binary classification. Because you have 1 output neuron with sigmoid activation function.

Then you should use use **binary_crossentropy** as loss function. Try to change:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
         optimizer='adam',
         metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Yeap, this fixed the loss values, but accuracy values are both still stays 0. What can I do about that?